# Image inside h:outputtext Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I add an image via style class inside a h:outputText ? Below is my code :

```
<h:outputText styleClass="postprocessedtick" rendered="#{filteredDump.postProcessed == 'YES'}" />
```

and the styleclass is as :

```
.postprocessedtick
{
    background-image: url(resources/images/yes.png);
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

I know primefaces provides a p:graphicimage tag as well but for some reason that I can't explain here, I need to do it in a outputText. I checked in the inspect element, I can see the style class applied to it as well the image link is also fine. I tried using !important as well but doesn't work.

Comment: @BalusC that didn't work I tried to change to #resources and rest similarly but the image simply doesn't load.

Comment: What's being returned instead as response to the image request?

Comment: How do I find the response? I can see in Inspect Element that the img link is there and when I hover over it, the image appears, one other question @BalusC can I use the image inside a primefaces datatable and make the image clickable?

Comment: Press F12 and open Network tab to see webbrowser's HTTP traffic monitor. If the image is delivered successfully, then your problem is caused elsewhere. E.g. the element isn't a block level element. The `<h:outputText>` renders by default a span which is an inline level element. You'd need to apply CSS `display:block` on it, or to replace it by e.g. `<div>`. CSS width/height have only effect on HTML block level elements.